# Is it possible to make sticky label for text which can be overflowed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

It's easy to understand what I want to do by looking at the following screenshots.

When there isn't too much text, I want the label to snuggle up to it.
[image]

When the text doesn't fit completely on one line, I want it to overflow like in the screenshot.
[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and knows how to do it in the proper way?

**UPDATE 1**
What have I already tried?

1. RichText

```dart
RichText(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [
        TextSpan(...),
        WidgetSpan(
          child: ...,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

2. Row with Expanded. As a result, as expected, the label is no longer pinned to the text.

   Row(
   children: [
   Expanded(
   child: Text(
   text,
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
   ),
   Label(),
   ],
   ),

Comment: Could you update your question to include a working example of what you have tried already? The community could then better answer your question.

Comment: Does your label is an image or just Text?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh
It's a widget, like a Container with flexible width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Row` with `Flexible<Text>` to handle this case.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        softWrap: false,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      color: Colors.amber,
    )
  ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: you can remove hard coded `width` and use `Text` widget

Comment: You are the best! I spend too much time and the fix was so easy. Thanks a lot!